# Passing context to an Angular 2 component's projected content (using ng-content)

Tags: typescript, angular, components

I'm writing a reusable Angular 2 component to retrieve and display data in a table, with server-side sorting, filtering and searching. I would like each row in the table to have an extra column with generic html using an ng-context tag, and I can do this.

The most common case for this is to have buttons which can do actions using the data each row was constructed from (say, navigate to a specific page for the entry, or delete the entry), but there doesn't seem to be a way to pass an object to the ContentChildren of a component. I could perhaps accomplish this via direct DOM manipulation and inspection, but that is both very hacky and bad for re-usability.

I'm not really concerned with any specific way to accomplish this, so long as it:

- Allows me to add generic html as a child of the component
- Can pass some generic data from the parent component to its ContentChildren (the aforementioned generic html) in such a way that it can be used by event handlers on the children.

I'm using typescript so a type-safe solution would be preferred, but I'd be happy having to ignore the type system if need be.

My table component (my-table) in use would look something like

```
<my-table /* some properties */>
    <button class="row-button" type="button" (click)="navigate(/* context */)">Navigate</button>
</my-table>
```

with its template using ng-content like so:

```
// table html
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <td *ngFor="let column of row.columns">{{column}}</td>
    <td>
        <ng-content select=".row-button"></ng-content>
    </td>
</tr>
// more table html
```

If I could pass a parameter to the ng-content which would be usable by the button element that would suffice.

Comment: It would help if you could add some code that shows a concrete example of what you try to accomplish. How does the "context" look like? Where does it come from? Where should it be available? What should happen to what exact property if X happens.

Comment: I've added some psudo-code, although I'm ambivalent about the actual way of implementing it.

The "context" would just be an object, which comes from the parent, and is usable in the template of the child (or however else I can accomplish it)

Comment: What is "parent"? Is `<my-table>` the parent or the component that contains the first code snippet in the template. In the later case this should just work if the parent has a `content` property in the component class.

Comment: <my-table> would be the generic component, which is the parent with the collection of rows/columns. The button in the first example would be projected into the <ng-content> tag inside of its template html. I'll update the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 8):

If you're not strict on usin ng-content, `ng-template` could do the work:

```
<my-table [rowButtonTemplate]="buttonTemplate" /* some properties */>
    <ng-template #buttonTemplate let-column>
        <button class="row-button" type="button" (click)="navigate(column.context)">Navigate</button>
    </ng-template>
</my-table>
```

and then inside table:

```
// table ts
@Input()
rowButtonTemplate: TemplateRef;


// table html
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <td *ngFor="let column of row.columns">{{column}}</td>
    <td>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="rowButtonTemplate; context: { $implicit: column, index: index }"></ng-container>
    </td>
</tr>
// more table html
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. Tried: project content into template | project template of content | ... (X compinations with ViewChild, ContentChild, ngContainer, ngContent). Insane that Angular provides no way through content projection alone.

Answer (score 6):

One way would be a template variable that allows you to explicitly refer to the parent:

```
<my-table #myTable>
  <button [context]="myTable.context">
</my-table>
```

As far as I know there are plans to make this more flexible. I guess it is this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563

Comment: This solution doesn't allow me to pass in the data from each individual row. Without having access to the index for the loop over the rows, I can't pass the correct row through to the child. I can see how it would otherwise work fine though, and I'll keep an eye on that issue.

Comment: I see where you're getting at. I didn't see that previously. Adding `<ng-content>` in `*ngFor` doesn't work this way anyway. Everything will be transcluded to the first `<ng-content>` tag with a matching selector.

Comment: There are plans to add support for this use case but I don't know how long this might take to land. I think this is the issue to follow https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563